# I have a python script that launches interactive renders in Maya and I would like my script's cancel button to stop the render like the 'esc' does

Tags: python, maya

I would like my python script's cancel function to interrupt the Maya render in the same was pressing the 'esc' key does. How would I mimic that behavior with my function?

google, autodesk site

I can interrupt the script with various functions, but I have not been able to esc out of an interactive render.

Comment: "interactive render" means a normal rendering from the UI but not an IPR rendering, ist that correct? If so I doubt that it is possible, since the UI usually blocks (depending on the renderer) until the rendering is done. So you cannot press your cancel button.

Comment: Thank you, I wondered about that. Can I mimic the 'esc' keyboard button function with my script's cancel button somehow? And your right, I do not mean IPR, I mean the interactive V-ray view port render that you can normally interrupt by pressing the 'esc' key.

Comment: In most renderers, the rendering process is enclosed by computeBegin() and computeEnd() commands. Every user UI action after computeBegin() is blocked, so you cannot press a button or execute a script. But that depends a lot on the renderer. There are renderers which do not block the UI during rendering so there could be a possibility, but in most implementations it does not work.

Comment: how does the ‘esc’ key command interrupt the render? Can I mimic that action somehow?

Comment: Simulating this action means you have to execute a script. As I mentioned before if you cannot execute a script because the UI is blocked, you cannot mimic this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

stopIprRendering renderView;
if using the render view

using echo all commands will usually have the command hidden in the script editor history.